Using kotlin coroutines alongside threads in a thread based web server application
I have a basic kotlin webserver application built using dropwizard and jersey, which uses threads for handling requests. I have been reading a lot lately on kotlin corooutines and seeing articles about preferring them over threads and I'm wondering how would I be able to introduce them into my application? To me it seems that unless I configure my entire application to use coroutines over threads from the ground up and handle requests using coroutines, it would be a bad idea to try introduce them as there would be two different conflicting concurrency scheduling patterns. Does anyone have any suggestions on what is good practice for using coroutines inside a thread based application like so?
Note: I get that in a coroutine system I might want to spin up as many threads as there are cores at start up to help support parallelism as well as concurrency, but I'm more focused on using threads and coroutines alongside each other in the application code.

I won't help you with details, but if a web server supports coroutines, it is often entirely fine to mix both worlds. One method is blocking (threads), another is suspending (coroutines). The server handles this internally. However, you may have problems with your own shared code, e.g. DB operations, etc. You may end up duplicating it for threads and for coroutines.

Mixing coroutines with other things is fine.

As it's usually the case, it depends, but I think you can still analyze it without even focusing on web servers, pretty much any scenario where you leverage some existing framework/library should have more or less the same considerations.
If you're implementing your code on top of a framework whose contract basically specifies "here's a thread to handle X, it's yours until you're done," it mostly doesn't matter if you introduce a different "nested" threading model, the framework won't care how you subdivide the tasks at that point (there are exceptions though, e.g. fork-join pools in the JVM, see for instance this JUnit issue).
This doesn't mean it will benefit you. For a web server handling "small" requests, it certainly won't help you scale the server's capacity unless the whole framework can reuse threads, but if the logic handling the requests needs to decompose the work somehow, that's a different story; see this example.
Moreover, the framework's contract can have limitations that will really forbid changing the threading model. I'd say it's common for frameworks to rely on thread-locals to handle and propagate state that can be used by other utilities provided by the framework, so you could end up with components that work in some contexts but not others because of this state that your own code doesn't manage and is required.
In my opinion, good practice in these cases basically boils down to: if you understand enough about the technicalities of the framework you're using, it should be possible to deduce what's possible and what isn't; if you don't understand enough (or the documentation of the framework isn't good enough), don't do it. And always measure performance in your scenario and compare.
